# Magento.... Nothing loading, whatsoever

Tags: sql, magento, indexing, config

I've just finished creating a Magento store for a friend and after altering the shipping settings, i got a page cannot be displayed error..

I quickly went to the homepage (which is hosted locally by the way [myshop.local]).
And the site loads, but no images or css/js is loading whatsoever. The url looks like this...

myshop.localindex.php/ on every page (missing a / after myshop.local).

I haven't modified any config settings to cause this to happen, and have no idea what could be causing the end / to be missing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your `core_config` table and make sure that the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` settings are correct.

In your case both should be http://myshop.local/

I've had what you describe above occur when I accidentally omit the slash at the end, as this breaks all references to CSS and images.

After you do this, make sure you go under var/cache and delete all folders (essentially clearing your cache).

Comment: Thank's Phil I managed to fix it about 2 hours after posting lol it did actually turn out that the core_config was misconfigured, and i didn't clean cache